# How to Link A Social Media Image in Rails Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using rails 4.0.0 and twitter bootstrap to design a simple landing page. I want social media icons to show up at the top of the pages next to the title. What is the "railsy" way of indicating an image with a link in Application.html.erb. The code I have so far looks like this

`<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li>
                    <%= link_to "Facebook" , "http://www.facebook.com/user" %>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <%= link_to "Twitter" , "http://www.twitter.com/user" %>
                </li>
            </ul>`
    How can I turn those links into images of the social media icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "http://www.facebook.com/user" do %>
      <%= image_tag 'facebook.png' %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "http://www.twitter.com/user" do %>
      <%= image_tag 'twitter.png' %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  # etc.
</ul>
```

This code will try to render the pictures "facebook.png" and "twitter.png" which should be located in the folder *app/assets/*

Documentation about image_tag: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag